# Testcafe report generaton - open source engine

Tags: testing, console, output, report, testcafe

I am planning to convert my testcafe console output to txt/html file with custom file name, I am using below line of script, but output file is not generating and no errors. I have installed the required report templates. Please guide me .

$ testcafe chrome tests/core/sample.test.js --reporter html:/file.html
$ testcafe chrome tests/core/sample.test.js --reporter list:/test.txt

Thanks
Ramesh D

Answer (score 2):

> console output to txt

Isn't this just easier?

```
$ testcafe chrome tests/core/sample.test.js > test_output.txt 2>&1
```

I mean you can use reporters, you can build your own reporter and spend hours on that, or if you really just need a file out of console output, this should be enough.

> console output to html

I have a habit of using config files rather than command line options, so I'll show it on config files:

**.testcaferc.json**

```json
{    
     "reporter": [        
        {
            "name": "html",
            "output": "Results/report.html"
        }
    ]
}
```

First, of course, you need to install the appropriate [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/testcafe-reporter-html):

```
$ npm install --save-dev testcafe-reporter-html
```

If you insist on a command-line option, this [testcafe docs](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/command-line-interface.html#-r-nameoutput---reporter-nameoutput) should guide you. I believe this would be the right command:

```
$ testcafe chrome tests/core/sample.test.js -r html:Results/report.html
```

Comment: Thanks you..it is working, I have tried with --$ testcafe chrome tests/core/sample.test.js -r html:Results/report.html